# understanding Jquery inside HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am writing this code here inside my HTML and I am trying to access the information in order to show and hide the information on the functioning website.

I have only been learning to code for less than a month and a half so I am unsure of whether or not this code creates another DIV inside the HTML.

If it does, how can I access this on CSS? I tried different methods to see if this would show up, but at this point, I believe it does not create anything new inside my HTML Body.

```
      *var $tweet = $('<div class="tweet' +tweet.user+'"></div>');
```

Comment: You have to append it `$("<div></div>").appendTo(document.body);`. Yes it creates a div, but it isn't attached to the DOM until you do something like that

Comment: Elements do not need to be integrated in the DOM ( ~ the html tree ), they are objects of their own. The html page hosting the javascript is agnostic of newly created elements until they are integrated into the html tree. The DOM API provides methods to do so, eg. `appendChild`. Re your example: after the integration of `$tweet` into the html tree, you can reference the element through its class - try `.class` (and remember, this will select other elements carrying the sameclass along with your new element). (PS: abstracting away here from the difference between a jquery object an a DOM node).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are creating an element but you are not appending it to anything.

```
var tweet = ('<div class="tweet' +tweet.user +'"></div>');
$('body').append(tweet);
```

you can change the 'body' to a different selector

Comment: Thank you so much! I was having trouble figuring out and unsure of how to test it. But that made so much sense. I'll revise the code.